# Writing Nested Form in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to write a nested form in ROR.
I have two tables `Employee` and `EmployeeInfo` and both table have a column named `employeeID`
these tables are connected with this key.
What i want to do is to create a form with some input fields which should update the values into both tables.

for eg i want a form which can create or update fields named `employee_name`, `age`, `address` and `city` But `employee_name` and `age` are present in table `Employee` and `city` and `address` are present in table `EmployeeInfo`.
So how should i write the form tag inorder to do this.
Please be sorry if question is a blunder. I'm realy new to this. Pls help

Comment: Which `Rails` version are you using?

Comment: And also what are the `associations` between those two tables?

Comment: @Pavan rails version is 4.0.0
thing is i dont know how to associate this two as im dont have the id of any tables in any one

Comment: You could have `employee has_many employee_infos` and `employee_info belongs_to employee` and relate them with `employee_id` as `FK` in `employee_infos` table.

Comment: @Pavan, it would be a has_one relation i guess because one employe has one information like his profile.

Comment: @emu yes,you are right.

Comment: May i know the reason?

Comment: @Pavan because i dont have the permission to. :(
is der anyother way to write the relation

Comment: As you have `employeeID` in both the tables,you can set it as `custom PK and FK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending **@emu's** answer

**Models setup**

```
#employee.rb
Class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :employe_info
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_info
end

#employee_info.rb
Class EmployeeInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

**Controller**

```
Class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @employee = Employee.new
      @employee.build_employee_info
   end

   def create
     @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

     if @employee.save
     redirect_to @employee
     else
     render 'new'
     end
   end

   private

   def employee_params
     params.require(:employee).permit(:employee_name, :age, employee_info_attributes: [:id, :city,:address])
   end
 end
```

Comment: @Pavan hey.. i managed to do it without employee_id by specifying employeeID as primary key n foreign key in both places..

Comment: @NidhinSG Glad you got it worked with my suggestion.And you should be posting a new question regarding your new error.

Comment: @Pavan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571532/activemodel-forbidden-error-in-rails-4-0-0

Answer (score 2):

In rails 4 you need to use

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :employeeinfo
```

in your **employee** model. And also **employee** has the relation with **emplyeeinfo** is `has_one`.

in the form:

```
<%= form_for @employe, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @employe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :employee_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :employee_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :age %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :employeeinfo do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :address %><br>
    <%= s.text_field :address %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Please edit the form objects according to your model name.**

Comment: wil this work if i dont i have employee_info_id inside employee table

Comment: @NidhinSG You should be having `employee_id` in the `employee_infos` table not `employee_info_id` in `employees` table.

Answer (score 1):

**Foriegn Key**

Firstly the "connector" key you're referring to is called a [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

This is a standard `relational database` feature, allowing you to "join" two or more databases together with a single reference point. Whenever you use [`associations` in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), you'll basically have to join the two datatables with a `foreign_key`

> both table have a column named employeeID

Your `employee_infos` table only needs to have the foreign_key `employee_id`:

```
#app/models/employee.rb
Class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :employee_info #-> foreign key = "employee_id"
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_info
end

#app/models/employee_info.rb
Class EmployeeInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employee
end
```

---

**Forms**

As mentioned by `Emu`, you'll need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

This allows you to pass data from a "parent" model to a child model, exactly what you have set up currently. The difference being you have to ensure you have it set up correctly.

Regardless of what you think, this is how you need to do it. You mention yourself that you're very new to Rails; which means your objections are *likely* based on your current DB setup. This might not be correct

You should use `emu` & `Pavan`'s answers to fix this :)