# How to create all required records to main with fields filled from web form in ror erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

It may be duplicate of for e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569668/writing-nested-form-in-ror) but my code not working without any error which will guide me.
I got Advert which has some references to other models (company[:id, :name]) and others like that. This models has `has_many :advert` declarations. 
I wanted to make form in which user will create Advert with this all fields. City has also `belongs_to :province`.

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :job_category
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :site

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_category

  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :date_link_added, presence: true
  validates :appointment, presence: true
  validates :site, presence: true
  validates :job_category, presence: true
  validates :date_last_verified, presence: true
end
```

I have adverts_controller with views/new.html.erb in which I have code like that:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@advert, label_col: "col-sm-6", control_col: "col-sm-6") do |fb| %>
                  <%= fb.url_field :url, label: "Original Link do advert" %>
                  <%= fb.fields_for :job_category do |j| %>
                    <%= j.text_field :name, label: "Job Category" %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= fb.fields_for :city do |c| %>
                    <%= c.collection_select :province_id, Province.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select ...", label: "Province"}, { class: "selectpicker form-control" } %>
                    <%= c.text_field :name, label: "City" %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= fb.fields_for :company do |c| %>
                    <%= c.text_field :name, label: "Company" %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= fb.text_field :appointment, label: "Appointment" %>
                  <%= fb.date_field :date_adv_added, label: "Release" %>
                  <%= fb.date_field :date_expiration, label: "Expire" %>
                  <%= fb.form_group :verified do %>
                      <%= fb.check_box :verified, label: "Verified" %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= link_to "<- Cancel", adverts_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <%= fb.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
```

Code in controller

```
   def create
    ad = advert_params
    @advert = Advert.new(ad)
    if(@advert.save)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to :back, alert: "Query failed. Check if all fields filled and try again later"
    end
  end

  private
  def advert_params
    adv_params = params.require(:advert).permit(:url, :date_adv_added, :date_expiration, :appointment, :verified, company_attributes: [:id, :name], job_category_attributes: [:id, :name], city_attributes: [:id, :name, :province_id])
  end
```

@advert.save is all the time returning false.
On console I got only:

```
  Advert Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `adverts`.* FROM `adverts`
  JobCategory Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `job_categories`.* FROM `job_categories` WHERE `job_categories`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `provinces`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  JobCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `job_categories`.* FROM `job_categories` WHERE `job_categories`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `provinces`.`id` = 13 LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  JobCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `job_categories`.* FROM `job_categories` WHERE `job_categories`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `provinces`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  JobCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `job_categories`.* FROM `job_categories` WHERE `job_categories`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `provinces`.`id` = 15 LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
  Rendered adverts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (31.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 138.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

And nothing is added to database.
I do not know what point I have missed.
My code without last changes is there [JAG](https://github.com/GRM-dev/JAG)
Anybody has a clue what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a print statement in the `create` action as follows and inspect your console. That should list any validation errors, which should give you an idea on whats causing the failure to save.

```
def create
  ad = advert_params
  @advert = Advert.new(ad)

  if(@advert.save)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    $stderr.puts @advert.errors.messages
    redirect_to :back, alert: "Query failed. Check if all fields filled and try again later"
  end
end
```

Comment: {:date_link_added=>["can't be blank"], :site=>["can't be blank"], :job_category=>["can't be blank"]}

Comment: Now you know what fields are missing. If you address those errors, you should be good.

Comment: ok. date_link_added and site I need to add manually, but job_category should be passed as like city and company, but it isn't.